# How can i change font size of Zebra CPCL for printing

Tags: flutter, zebra-printers, zpl

I have been working with an android mobile application on Flutter.
I need to print a label. I'm using a zebra printer that model is ZQ510.

When I send CPCL text to the printer by Bluetooth it works and prints out. But the printed output is really small. How can I make it bigger?

here is my CPCL text;

```
{D0611,0325,0591|}
{C|}
{XB00;0040,0369,A,3,02,0,0084,+0000000000,000,0,00=>512345678|}
{PC000;0094,0458,10,10,02,00,B=12345678|}
{PC001;0060,0048,10,10,01,00,B=149,95 |}
{PC002;0023,0170,10,10,02,00,B=Fiyat tarihi:|}
{PC003;0143,0170,10,10,02,00,B=24.08.2021|}
{PC004;0023,0215,10,10,03,00,B=T88001314CUT-|}
{PC005;0023,0240,10,10,03,00,B=GREY MARL-2-3 Y-|}
{PC006;0023,0271,10,10,02,00,B=Minecraft Tee|}
{PC007;0021,0313,10,10,02,00,B=Üretim Yeri:|}
{PC008;0143,0313,10,10,02,00,B=Türkiye|}
{LC;0063,0069,0199,0069,0,8|}
{PC009;0086,0113,10,10,01,00,B=49,99 |}
{PC000;0070,0500,06,06,010,00,B|}
{RC000;A|}
{XS;I,0001,0002C6200|}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to increase the horizontal and vertical magnification; in your code, replace the `...,10,10,...` of the PC commands with ex. `20,20` and see if it is better. Reference: page 63 [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/software/linkos/vd-t-ug-en.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, @evilmandarine. it is better now. I have a question. I added the output of the print to the above. the printing starting at the end of the label. how can I change the position of values?

Comment: First this is TPCL, not ZPL, so you should correct the tag in the question. Try to calibrate your printer. If this does not work, I suggest you ask another question. I'm commenting instead of answering because I am no TPCL expert.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need CPCL? IMO is kind of limited. Change your configuration to ZPL ([instructions from zebra.com](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/how-to-enable-zpl-or-line-print-mode-on-mobile-printers.html)) and then use my source code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384323/flutter-bluetooth-printing-to-zebra/59444229#59444229)

One more thing: keep in mind that if you want to print special language characters (I see that you need to print Turkish) you have to find the correct font that is installed in your printer. For example: In order to print Greek characters I have to integrate this

> ^CWN,E:TT0003M_.FNT

just after the first ^XA. Then I use the N font in order to print Greek. It is very flexible if you understand the basics

For example if you send this

```
^XA
^CWN,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CI28
^CFN,20,20
^FO50,50^FDΧώρα Παραγωγής: ^FS
^FO50,90^FDΠεριοχή: ^FS

^CFN,30,30
^FO250,45^FDΕλλάδα^FS
^FO250,85^FDΒΙΠΕ Ηρακλείου^FS
^XZ
```

**You will get this**

[image: this]
Hope it helps